# ui-router fires transition to root state as soon as controller loaded

Tags: angular-ui-router, angular-ui-router-extras

has anyone seen this sort of behaviour before ?

I have a button that is defined like this

```
<button ui-sref="designer({model: 'foobar' })">
```

I have a state defined as this

```
{
  name: 'designer',
  state: {
    url: 'designer/:model/:form',
    templateUrl: '/partials/designer.html',
    controller: 'DesignerController',
    controllerAs: 'designer'
  }
}
```

and a controller like this

```
(function() {
    angular.module('myApp')
        .controller('DesignerController', DesignerController)

    function DesignerController() {
        console.log("-->loaded designer");
    }
})();
```

when I click on the button, I get this in the  console (I've added some debugging)

```
$stateChangeSuccess to designer- fired once the state transition is complete.

-->loaded designer

$viewContentLoaded - fired after dom rendered Object {name: "$viewContentLoaded", targetScope: ChildScope, defaultPrevented: false, currentScope: Object}

$stateChangeStart to undefined- fired when the transition begins. toState,toParams : 
 Object {url: "/", templateUrl: "/partials/main.html", name: "root", status: "exited", onExit: undefined} Object {}

$stateChangeSuccess to root- fired once the state transition is complete.
```

as you can see - as soon as the designer controller is loaded, a transition to the root state is fired - what can cause that ?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in transitionTo. What invokes it?

Comment: i've been trying to figure out how to do that for a few hours now ;) Do i need to load up the angular code to do this ?

Comment: make sure you're not using the minfiied version of angular-ui-router. Load up chrome dev-tools. Hit ctrl-O and type "ui-router" (it should find and load angular-ui-router.js src). In the src file, hit ctrl-F to find "function transitionTo".  Put a breakpoint at the start of that function.